# React-Router: how to hide Home page when linked component is opened?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an **API call**, and I display all the **items**. Now I want to display more information for any **item**, user clicks, via **React-Router**. For now after clicking to the **link**  it redirect to the linked component, but the Home page doesn't disappear. How to hide it?
Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my Routes components, which is imported in App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import CountryCard from './CountryCard'
import TableRow from './components/TableRow'

const Routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/TableRow" component={TableRow} />
    <Route path="/TableRow/:id" component={CountryCard} />
  </Switch>
)
export default Routes
```

in MainTable component I am mapping through the fetched data

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import Header from '../Header'
import TableRow from '../TableRow'
import ThemeContext from '../../useContext/context'

import './mainTable.scss'

export default function MainTable({ countries }: any) {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')
    body[0].style.backgroundColor = theme.foreground
  }, [theme.foreground])

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <table className="table">
        <tbody className="tableBody">
          {countries &&
            countries.map((country?: any) => (
              <TableRow
                key={country.name}
                flagUrl={country.flag}
                countryName={country.name}
                languages={country.languages}
                population={country.population}
                region={country.region}
              />
            ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

in TableRow component I display items and create link for the item's name

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import Flag from '../Flag'

import { TableRowProps } from '../../types'
import ThemeContext from '../../useContext/context'

import './tableRow.scss'

export default function TableRow({
  flagUrl,
  countryName,
  languages,
  population,
  region,
}: TableRowProps) {
  const { theme } = useContext(ThemeContext)

  return (
    <tr className="tableRow">
      <td>
        <Flag flag={flagUrl} />
      </td>
      <td>
        {
          <Link
            to={`/index/${countryName}`}
            style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}
          >
            {countryName}
          </Link>
        }
      </td>
      <td>
        {languages &&
          languages.map((lang: any) => <li key={lang.name}>{lang.name}</li>)}
      </td>
      <td>{population}</td>
      <td>{region}</td>
      <td>
        <button className="AddButton" style={{ color: theme.foreground }}>
          ADD
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  )
}
```

CountryCard component

```
import React from 'react'

export default function CountryCard() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your route.

```
<Link
   to={`/TableRow/${countryName}`}
   style={{ color: 'inherit', textDecoration: 'inherit' }}>
   {countryName}
</Link>
```

URL should match with created routes - (path - to) should match.

Are you looking something like this [Example of nested routing](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-custom-link-forkedso-fow00?file=/example.js). You can uderstand and change as per your requirement.

Comment: Hey @Vahid Akhtar thanks for answer. Actually it's TableRow/index.js, that's why I wrote index. 
I changed  to "TableRow", but  didn't help.

Comment: @Greg if you need an index in your route then define it in routes first

Comment: Hey @Vahid Akhtar still no result